# Solr loading all document into cache

Tags: database, caching, solr

I have a Core with 500k documents inside them. Is there any concept in Solr similar to loading all of that Core into cache/Ram to allow maximum read/write speed without having to resort to hard disk

Comment: Your OS usually handles this very well for you by caching the segments as they're read, as well as the internal cache in Solr with warming queries. You can use `vmtouch` to warm the OS cache as well - exactly where are you experiencing issues (is it an IO issue, query issue, cpu issue, etc?), and are you using any existing warming queries?

Comment: It is not really an issue, rather i would like to always load full solr into cache for fastest search as possible